# Org mode export to html: onmouseover highlighting of referenced code lines

Tags: org-export

Section `Markup for Rich Contents/Literal Examples` in org documentation contains the following text:

> In literal examples, Org interprets strings like ‘(ref:name)’ as
> labels, and use them as targets for special hyperlinks like
> ‘[[(name)]]’—i.e., the reference name enclosed in single parenthesis.
> In HTML, hovering the mouse over such a link remote-highlights the
> corresponding code line, which is kind of cool.

It then uses the following example:

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp -n -r
   (save-excursion                 (ref:sc)
      (goto-char (point-min))      (ref:jump)
 #+END_SRC
 In line [[(sc)]] we remember the current position. [[(jump)][Line (jump)]] jumps to point-min.
```

I remember to have had it work, but it doesn't work any more.  I mean, when I put the mouse on the link in the generated html, nothing is highlighted.

Looking at the generated html I can see referenced lines are put in a `span`

```
<div class="org-src-container">
<pre class="src src-emacs-lisp"><span id="coderef-sc" class="coderef-off"><span class="linenr">1: </span>       (<span style="color: #531ab6;">save-excursion</span></span>
<span id="coderef-jump" class="coderef-off"><span class="linenr">2: </span>          (goto-char (point-min))</span>
</pre>
</div>
<p>
```

And the reference is given an `onmouseover` event calling a `CodeHighlightOn` javascript function:

```
In line <a href="#coderef-sc" class="coderef" onmouseover="CodeHighlightOn(this, 'coderef-sc');" onmouseout="CodeHighlightOff(this, 'coderef-sc');">1</a> we remember the current position. <a href="#coderef-jump" class="coderef" onmouseover="CodeHighlightOn(this, 'coderef-jump');" onmouseout="CodeHighlightOff(this, 'coderef-jump');">Line 2</a>
jumps to point-min.
```

So I guess the problem is I lack the javascript code defining these `CodeHighlightOn` and `CodeHighlightOff` functions.

So the question is: where are these functions defined? (and why don't I have them, the documentation suggests it should work out of the box).

This is org mode 9.6.11 on emacs 30.0.50.

Comment: Check the value of `org-html-head-include-scripts`: it's `t` by default but maybe you have turned it off?

Comment: To expand a bit on the previous comment, the functions are defined in the string `org-html-scripts`  at the top of `ox-html.el`, which is inlined into the HTML file by `org-html--build-head` *if* `org-html-head-include-scripts` is non-nil.

Comment: Actually, it seems the default value is `nil` in the sense that `emacs -Q` starts with that value. But I'm tired and confused and need sleep, so maybe this is all wrong.

Comment: You're right: setting `org-html-head-include-scripts` to `t` does solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: So I was right, even though I was tired and confused: see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to customize `org-html-head-include-scripts` and set it to `t`. With that setting, `org-html--build-head` includes the string `org-html-scripts` in the `head` section of the HTML document: that string includes the definitions of the JS functions, `CodeHighlightOn` and `CodeHighlightOff`.

---

EDIT: The following analysis was done in an old branch of the Org mode source. The current code (since release 9.5 in 2021) has changed the default value of the variable to `nil` for unrelated reasons (basically, LibreJS was complaining that "public domain" is no license and not always recognized around the world - see the discussion [here](https://list.orgmode.org/877dl2rn5i.fsf@disroot.org/)).

So the following analysis is obsolete (but the solution above is actually the correct solution to the question, with no need of quotation marks any more.)

The theoretical problem still exists of course, but since this was the only known instance of it, the point is moot.

---

[**Warning**: **the following analysis is obsolete - see EDIT above**.]

But why is `org-html-head-include-scripts` `nil` to begin with? The `defcustom` that defines it says:

```el
(defcustom org-html-head-include-scripts t ...
```

so why isn't it `t`?

Reading the [description of `defcustom`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Variable-Definitions.html#index-defcustom) in the Emacs Lisp manual provides a clue:

> The argument `standard` is an expression that specifies the standard value for option. Evaluating the `defcustom` form evaluates `standard`, but does not necessarily bind the option to that value. If option already has a default value, it is left unchanged. If the user has already saved a customization for option, the user’s customized value is installed as the default value. Otherwise, the result of evaluating standard is installed as the default value.

Note, btw, that this detail is not included in the doc string of `defcustom`, so `C-h f defcustom` was not enlightening - perhaps it *should* be included in the doc string.

So somebody must be binding `org-html-head-include-scripts` to `nil` *before* the `defcustom` is evaluated. The only other use of the variable is when the HTML backend is created by `org-export-define-backend` in `ox-html.el` and that call textually precedes the `defcustom` in the file, so when the file is loaded, `org-export-define-backend` is called first, and presumably binds `org-html-head-include-scripts` to `nil`, so when the `defcustom` is evaluated, the standard value is set to `t` but the actual value remains at `nil`. I verified that if I move the `defcustom` in the file to before the call to `org-export-define-backend` everything works as expected (or at least as *I* expect it).

This looks like a bug to me, so I'll submit a bug report to Org mode to get the code fixed. I might also submit a doc bug to Emacs to get the missing detail into the doc string of `defcustom`. I'll update this answer with that information when done.

Comment: Thanks for the nice in depth analysis of the issue, and for the bug report.

Comment: About the edit: oh my! Thanks for clarifying that.  This is still a bug in org-mode documentation (should mention the need to set `org-html-head-include-scripts` to `t` to get the advertised behavior) isn't it?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll change the bug report to a doc bug and submit a patch.